# No view found for id 0x7f0800be (com.example.progetto:id/fragment_container_view) for fragment HomeFragment{xx} (xxxx id=0x7f0800be tag=HomeFragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, fragmenttransaction

I've read these questions/answers:

- [Android Fragment no view found for ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id)
- [No view found for id for fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177357/no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment)
- [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x1020002 (android:id/content) for fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665642/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-0x1020002-androidid-c)
- [IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id for fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843497/illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment)

But I couldn't really solve my problem, so here I am asking you!

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/topbar"/>
    <include layout="@layout/card_layout"/>
    <include layout="@layout/buttons"/>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.onCreate()

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //if there was no configuration change, create the fragment
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        Utilities.insertFragment(this, new HomeFragment(), FRAGMENT_TAG_HOME);

    addViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(AddViewModel.class);
}
```

part of AddFragment.java

```
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_view),
                "No Internet Available",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(R.string.settings, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                        intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

insertFragment method from Utilities.java

```
    static void insertFragment(AppCompatActivity activity, Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container_view with this fragment,
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, fragment, tag);

    //add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
    if (!(fragment instanceof HomeFragment) && !(fragment instanceof SettingsFragment)) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    }

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I know the linked questions are similars but I couldn't solve my situation

Here's my logcat:

```
Process: com.example.progetto, PID: 32561
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800be (com.example.progetto:id/fragment_container_view) for fragment HomeFragment{162338d} (62f9659c-9c9e-4173-977c-2f61675677bd id=0x7f0800be tag=HomeFragment)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3134)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3068)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:501)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1433)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7924)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3332)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Hello! Do you figured out this crash?